Installed VSCode in user mode, but always launches as admin
I have no need to install VS Code system wide, but it always launches as an admin which prevents it from updating. How do I get it to open in user-mode?
I am trying to do this on Windows 2019 Server

how exactly are you launching it? how are you sure that it's running with admin privileges?

Maybe this is beside the point (I'm not sure how Windows Server works), but why are you running VSCode on a server? Do you not have a workstation you can use?

@wjandrea I asked them how they're running. maybe they're running code tunnel ...? we'll have to wait until huntantr replies to know :/

I have it installed to develop and test automation that runs on a server.
As for how I am running it, nothing special. I am not asking it to run as an admin it just is and I can't figure out how to make it stop. I downloaded the install, installed it, and then clicked on the icon to run it.
